# Alternative to cast function in join when it comes to stored proc optimisation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the best alternative for cast function used to convert datatype in SQL query inside stored proc where join is used?

I have read often that its not good to use function and need help with optimization of query below.

```
SELECT 
    A.DATE,
    A.Value curr , 
     ISNULL( CAST( CONVERT ( DECIMAL(18,4),  CASE WHEN @INV = 0 THEN   NULLIF(ISNULL(tblRate.currBid,0),0)     ELSE  1.00  /    NULLIF(ISNULL(tblRate.currBid,0) ,0)  END  ) AS VARCHAR) ,@TempHardcodeValue)  AS  currBid,
     A.Value +' - '+ A.currName As ConcatenatedCurr
FROM #TEMPTable A
LEFT JOIN  tblCurrRates (NOLOCK) tblRate ON A.Date = cast(tblRate.currDate as date) AND A.currCode = tblRate.currCode
ORDER BY A.Date ,A.Value
```

As you can see cast function is used, so is there any other way to reqrite without cast?

Comment: Currencybid is datatype money

Comment: What is the datatype of `tblRate.currDate` and why are you casting it to date? Is it to strip the time portion off? You could write the join as an equi join on code and range predicate on date, which may be beneficial if you have nested loops and an appropriate index to support the seek. Otherwise the CAST would actually help as with both predicates equi join this is helpful for MERGE or HASH join

Comment: curr date's datatype is datetime

Comment: Stop splattering [NOLOCK hints](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) 
everywhere. They are not consequence free and you should use them only when you understand exactly what they do and **know** they are needed. And no - there is no way to avoid the conversion without changing the schema. Casting as varchar without a length is sloppy. Formatting of numeric values should be left to the consumer of the data - not the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, SQL Server is probably okay with the cast.  The one exception to using functions is casting date/times to dates -- SQL Server recognizes the conversion for the use of indexes.

But, you can do:

```
FROM #TEMPTable A LEFT JOIN 
     tblCurrRates r
     ON r.currDate >= A.Date AND
        r.currDate < DATEADD(day, 1, A.Date) AND   
        r.currCode = a.currCode
```

This would allow the code to use an index on `tblCurrRates(currCode, currDate)`.  I suspect, though, that your code would also use that index.